# Windows 10 Mobile NFC HCE

Tags: uwp, paypal, nfc, windows-10-mobile

Всем привет!
Сейчас пишу одного большое приложение для банка на UWP (Универсальная Платформа Виндовс), но оно нацеленно в ближайшее время только на Windows 10 Mobile. Я хочу с помощью телефона считать информацию с кредитной карты (базовая информация, которая доступна для считывания: номер карты, имя владельца и срок эксплуатации). Я знаю, что в Win10 для телефонов добавили HCE (Эмуляция кредитный карт), но я хотел бы узнать, возможно ли считать информацию без ее использования? 
Если это возможно, то как можно это сделать? Если же все таки нет, то как сделать это лучше с помощью HCE?

Comment: вы неправильно вопрос ставите. если вы пишите приложение для банка, то всю необходимую информацию они должны были вам предоставить. ну и наконец, опишите, что уже пробовали, и что именно не получилось.

Comment: Дело немного не в этом. Информации у меня достаточно. Мой камень преткновения это лишь Read Mode в Windows Phone (Windows 10 Mobile). Я не могу корректно считать данные с карты, так так не совсем помнимаю, как это работает.